# Scaling WordPress User Queries

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have over 50,000 registered users in my WP_Users table. Often times I need to run queries that check and count the different states of my users as a whole.

I often write something like the following.

```
$users = get_users(); //This query is not limited I need to run across all my users.
  $active_users = 0;
  foreach ($users as $user) {
    $last_transaction_date = strtotime(get_user_meta($user_id, 'last_trans_date', true));
    $next_recurring_date = strtotime(get_user_meta($user_id, 'next_recurring_date', true));
    $todays_date = strtotime('now');

    if ($todays_date >= $last_transaction_date && $todays_date <= $next_recurring_date ) {
      $active_users++;
    }

  }
```

The problem with this is that it is generating 2 database calls per user so it's incredibly slow and prone to making things crash. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You should do only two queries to wp_usermeta table
like this

STEP1

```
$SQLresult1 = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT user_id, meta_value
    FROM wp_usermeta
    WHERE meta_key = 'last_trans_date' 
        AND $todays_date >= meta_value
");


//convert it to array
SQLarr1 = [];

foreach ($SQLresult1 as &$item) {
    SQLarr1[$item->user_id] = $item->meta_value
}
```

STEP2

```
$SQLresult2 = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT user_id, meta_value
    FROM wp_usermeta
    WHERE meta_key = 'next_recurring_date' 
        AND $todays_date <= meta_value
");


//convert it to array
SQLarr2 = [];

foreach ($SQLresul2 as &$item) {
    SQLarr2[$item->user_id] = $item->meta_value
}
```

STEP3

```
$active_users = 0;

foreach ($SQLarr1 as $user_id => &$item) {
    if (isset($SQLarr2[$user_id]))
        $active_users++;
}
```

I didn't check this code. But you can see main idea